# How get a value from mysql in prestashop?

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to get a value from a table like that:

```
SELECT id_image FROM `ps_image` WHERE id_product = 903 limit 1
```

How can i integrate this sql command in prestashop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$product_id = '903';

$query = Db:: getInstance()->getRow(
'SELECT id_image FROM '._ DB_PREFIX_.'image WHERE id_product ='. $product_id
);
```

Use $query variable to get id of image.